# Using varibles in subroutines without passing them in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I start to work on an older Fortran code that uses heavily the following "feature":

```
subroutine sample 
        integer*4 :: a, b
    
        a = 1
        b = 1

        call increment(b)

        print *, a, b ! Prints "2 2"

contains
        subroutine increment(c)
                implicit none
                integer*4, intent(inout) :: c

                c = c + 1
                a = a + 1

        end subroutine increment
end subroutine sample
```

On multiple occasions in the code, a variable from a subroutine is used in (sub)subroutine without passing it through arguments. Before someone points it out, I don't think this is a good coding paradigm, but it is a code I should work on, and I have to deal with it.

My problem is I cannot find in the Fortran language reference if this is actually legal. I never used this "feature" I thought it is not legal but this code works for 20 years compiled with GCC, intel Fortran, pgi, nvhpc without a problem. Very recently I tried to compile it with one-API, but on multiple occasions, the variables in (sub)subroutine contained rubbish data (but not all the time).

My question is if this is actually a legal thing to do? Is it only a part of other compilers dialects? Or is it an oneapi's bug?

Comment: This is known as "host association" and is perfectly normal and legal. There are various caveats which must be noted (aliasing and so on) but these don't apply here. If you have a question about specific problematic code then please [edit] your question to be about that.

Comment: I see, I didn't know it is called "host association". Now I can find a lot of information about it.  Since my question is linked with a better question I will delete this one.

Comment: There is no need to delete this question just because it is linked to others as a duplicate. (Of course, you are free to.)